# EXCEL- Return Value of 3rd Column After Matching Multiple Columns In Two Sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sheet1:

```
FID YEAR    Type
1   2009    #N/A
1   2010    #N/A
1   2011    #N/A
1   2012    #N/A
1   2013    #N/A
1   2014    #N/A
1   2015    #N/A
1   2016    #N/A
3   2008    #N/A
3   2009    #N/A
3   2010    #N/A
3   2011    #N/A
3   2012    #N/A
3   2013    #N/A
3   2014    #N/A
3   2015    #N/A
3   2016    #N/A
```

Sheet2:

```
fID Year    Type
3   2014    DP
3   2012    DP
3   2011    DP
4           CU
4           CU
4           CU
4           CU
6   2013    CU
6   2013    CU
```

IF [FID+Year] in Sheet1 matches [fID+Year] in Sheet2, I want to copy Type Value from Sheet2 to Sheet1.

What I have tried till now using StackOverflow Q/A: [for row 2, the pattern repeated for remaining rows]

`=INDEX(Sheet2!A:D,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!A:A=A2)*(Sheet2!B:B=B2),0),3)` gives `#N/A`

`=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A2&B2,Sheet2!$A:A&Sheet2!$B:B,0),1)` gives `#N/A`

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from adding a fourth column for the composite key? The easiest solution is often the best.

Comment: You do know that this are array formulas which need to be confirmed via ctrl+shift+enter?

Comment: I just realized this while searching for the composite key. It works as array formula. But it's way to slow for thousands of rows. Is there a faster way to do this.

Comment: Let me look into the composite key. I am pretty new to excel.

Comment: With array formulas you need to not use full column references but only reference the dataset.

Comment: @urwaCFC If you add composite key in Sheet2 you can use VLOOKUP as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sheet 1 and 2, insert a column to the left of Column A.
In that column, add a composite key like =B2&C2 for both sheet.

This groups the value of both column together and makes it easier to lookup for it.

In sheet 1's "Type" column, add =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10,4,FALSE),"") if the top cell and drag it down. A2 is a cell from the composite key column, Sheet2!$A$1:$D$10 is the range of Sheet 2's table.